# ssh v2 maximum compression (xzip/7zip)

Tags: ssh, compression, socks

I am on a slow dial-up connection, but I have root access to a fast server.

Currently I use ssh v2 to connect to the server with Compression enabled in ~/.ssh/config. However this only uses gzip level 6 (as mentioned here https://serverfault.com/questions/388658/ssh-compression/.

However, it is possible to use better algorithms (like xzip with -e9 or 7zip with -mx=9 ) using pipes as mentioned here [https://serverfault.com/a/586739/506887]. The example in that answer:

```
ssh ${SSH_USER}@${SSH_HOST} "
    echo 'string to be compressed' | gzip -9
" | zcat | echo -
```

compresses a single string using xzip and pipes on the remote server.

1) I would like to do this (compress with xzip) for all traffic.How can that be done.

2) To save data, when I run firefox on my client, I use a socks v5 proxy with ssh to take advantage of compression

```
ssh -D 8123 -C   -v  -N root@myserver
```

and I point firefox to socks://localhost:8123. Again this using gzip level 6. Can this example be similarly modified to use xzip or 7zip.

I am aware that the bandwidth advantage of using xzip vs gzip may not be significant for a single connection. But I am hoping the bandwith savings will accumulate to a significant amount over a period of time.

Thanks

Comment: Unsuitable buffering appears to be a blocker for gaining anything from simply piping it like in your example. But you could simply use the `CompressionLevel`s of openssh to prove that this will be pointless anyway. Can't compress HTTPS.

Comment: that seems like a valid point. In that case is there any alternative to using pipes? I tried mosh but it did'nt help a lot with bandwidth ( it gives a more reliable connection though). It is true that https can be compressed significantly, and nowadays thats most of the web traffic. But it would still be useful to me to compress vanilla ssh login sessions, since I get charged per Mb by my data carrier.